# How to differentiate IP-addresses from domain names during parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, networking, dns, ip-address

I'm building an application where the user gets to specify the server to connect to, either by specifying the IP-address or domain name of the server. But how do I parse this input so the application knows if it is an IP-address or a domain name? What is it that differentiates an IP-address from a DNS record?

I tried to add an IP-address as the domain name in our DNS-server. And it worked. I can now resolve for example 192.168.30.230 to 10.0.0.1. I can even ping it (As I have a device on 10.0.0.1). That however requires me to add a `.` (dot) after the address to force `ping` to look it up. Otherwise it would use it like an IP-address. A.k.a not look it up.

DNS setup looked something like this:

```
RECORD    DNS Address       IP-Adress
A         192.168.30.230    10.0.0.1
```

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe>ping 192.168.30.230.

Pinging 192.168.30.230 [10.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Is it true that IP-addresses and domain names are interchangeable or can I do any assumptions when parsing the user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the user input with regex, just like the ping command does. Below example should match any numeric variation from `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`. Anything that doesn't match should be treated as a domain name.

```
/^(?=.*[^\.]$)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.?){4}$/
```

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought. But then I tested to do the redirection of the IP with DNS. And started to wonder why that worked... Is it just the fact that I'm adding the dot in the end that doesn't make it go through the regex? And some rule in DNS that says that dots should be ignored? Which results in the IP working as a domain name?

Comment: An ip address consists of 4 sequences of numbers ranging from 0 to 255, each sequence separated by a dot. Once you add a 4th dot, it's no longer an ip-address. That's why your redirect worked.

Comment: Yes, but why is that last dot ignored during lookup? I don't have any dot in the end of the A-host record in the DNS server. Are they ignored by some DNS specification?

Comment: That's more to do with how your shell/terminal interprets dots. CMD interprets it as a wildcard for regex (match everything before dot and everything after). Try the below commands for some more clarity:
`ping 10.1`
ping "10.1"
ping 10.0.0.1
ping "10.0.0.1"
ping 192.168.30.230
ping "192.168.30.230"